# How to draw a curve in XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

i am developing an app, which display the curve colored like this and the length of it i can change (in code), but i don't know how to do that, can anybody help me:[image]

Thank you !

Comment: [Quickstart: Shapes for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj207026(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Can you give me a sample for this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jerry Nixon posted [a blog](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/08/walkthrough-lets-build-control-like.html) and [walk through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyGqmW_ryZE) on creating this exact same control.

It builds on a previous [blog about building dials](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/12/walkthrough-building-sweet-dial-in-xaml.html).